# NVIDIA Quadro T1000 Mobile graphics driver issue Ubuntu 22.04.2

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, 22.04, ubuntu-drivers

Recently I upgraded and installed a fresh copy of Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on my Lenovo ThinkPad P53, it has a NVIDIA Quadro T1000 Mobile graphics card but ever since moving from Ubuntu 20 I've struggled to have a stable install of any NVIDIA driver and instead used the Nouveau driver.

OS: Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (Jammy) (source: `lsb_release -a`)

Graphics: NVIDIA Corporation TU117GLM [Quadro T1000 Mobile] (rev a1) (source: `lspci | grep VGA`)

Under the "Additional Drivers" section of Software & Updates I've got a full list of available drivers but if I switch to any of them I either reboot to a login loop whereby I login and then return to the login screen until I uninstall the driver, or the machine is laggy, crashes, external display is barely usable.

[image]

Comment: I am having the same issue (exactly the same Laptop and Graphic card). While running ubuntu on wayland monitors and everything else works fine, but some functionalities like screen sharing on Microsoft Teams doesn't work. 
If I switch to xOrg than sharing works, but external monitors just have white screen.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same graphics card in a Thinkpad P15 Gen1 (with Ubuntu 22.04 installed). Previously, I was using the "metapackage from nvidia-driver-525 (proprietary)" and everything was working fine, including screen sharing. However, after some regular updates on June 17, 2023, the second monitor stopped functioning.

On June 17, 2023, the following package was installed:

```
2023-06-17 09:16:51 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:51 remove linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1 <none>
2023-06-17 09:16:51 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:51 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:54 status config-files linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:56 status installed linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:56 remove linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1 <none>
2023-06-17 09:16:56 status half-configured linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:56 status half-installed linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:57 status config-files linux-objects-nvidia-525-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:59 status installed linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:59 remove linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1 <none>
2023-06-17 09:16:59 status half-configured linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:59 status half-installed linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:59 status config-files linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 5.19.0-42.43~22.04.1
2023-06-17 09:16:59 status not-installed linux-signatures-nvidia-5.19.0-42-generic:amd64 <none>
```

Today, after installing some new updates, the issue seems to be resolved. I cannot guarantee that this fix will solve the exact problem mentioned in this post, but it might be worth a try.

```
2023-06-20 09:55:32 upgrade linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+1 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2
2023-06-20 09:55:32 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+1
2023-06-20 09:55:32 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+1
2023-06-20 09:55:32 status half-installed linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+1
2023-06-20 09:55:32 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2
2023-06-20 09:55:44 configure linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2 <none>
2023-06-20 09:55:44 status unpacked linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2
2023-06-20 09:55:44 status half-configured linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2
2023-06-20 09:55:46 status installed linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.19.0-43-generic:amd64 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1+2
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the same issues: All the content elsewhere did not help including guidance provided under https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/nvidia-drivers-installation

The only thing that worked was the new Beta version of the Linux X64 (AMD64/EM64T) Display Driver. Download it here - https://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/212964/en-us/
and install through the terminal